# How to get Annotation metadata in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, code-generation

I am using [package:analyzer](https://pub.dev/packages/analyzer) package. I have extended `SimpleElementVisitor` to visit all the fields of the class. `visitFieldElement(FieldElement element)` is providing all the fields data type and fields name. But some of the fields are annotated with custom annotation. How I can read the metadata of that annotation?

Comment: Metadata can appear before a library, class, typedef, type parameter, constructor, factory, function, field, parameter, or variable declaration and before an import or export directive.

Check this [link](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#metadata) hope will help.

Answer (score 1):

From the `Element` instance (A `FieldElement` in the example) you can use the [`metadata` field](https://pub.dev/documentation/analyzer/latest/dart_element_element/Element/metadata.html) to read out annotations.

Comment: I'm unable to get FieldElement.metadata to show annotations or metadata. Docs say `Return a list containing all of the metadata associated with this element. The array will be empty if the element does not have any metadata or if the library containing this element has not yet been resolved.` How do we "resolve the library containing this element"?