# How to read the Annotation fields and their values (Code Generation)

Tags: flutter, dart

i have been struggling to get the fields from an annotation.

I am using the source code generator to generate my widget from my annotation but cant seem to use the annotation fields, how can i access the fields and the values.

My Annotation:

```
class CoreEntity {
  final String label;

  const CoreEntity({
    this.label,
  });
}
```

Using the annotation:

```
@CoreEntity(
  label: 'User',
)
class User {
  String email;
}
```

My Widget Generator:

```
class CoreWidgetGenerator extends GeneratorForAnnotation<CoreEntity> {
  @override
  FutureOr<String> generateForAnnotatedElement(
      Element element, ConstantReader annotation, BuildStep buildStep) {
    return _generateWidgetSource(element);
  }

  String _generateWidgetSource(Element element) {
    final anotData = element.metadata;
    for (ElementAnnotation el in anotData) {
      el.computeConstantValue();
      var elVisitor = ModelVisitor();
      el.element.visitChildren(elVisitor);
      print("1 ${elVisitor.className}"); // this prints out null
      print("2 ${elVisitor.fields}"); // this prints out empty list {}
    }
}

class ModelVisitor extends SimpleElementVisitor {
  DartType className;
  Map<String, DartType> fields = Map();

  @override
  visitConstructorElement(ConstructorElement element) {
    className = element.type.returnType;
    return super.visitConstructorElement(element);
  }

  @override
  visitFieldElement(FieldElement element) {
    fields[element.name] = element.type;

    return super.visitFieldElement(element);
  }
}
```

Packages in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  build: ^1.1.6
  source_gen: ^0.9.4+4 
  core_widget:
    path: ../core_widgets
```

Build Script (build.yaml)

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      core_gen|core_widget:
        enabled: true

builders:
  core_widget:
      target: ":core_gen"
      import: "package:core_gen/builder.dart"
      builder_factories: ["coreWidget"]
      build_extensions: {".dart":[".core_widget.g.part"]}
      auto_apply: dependents
      build_to: cache
      applies_builders: ["source_gen|combining_builder"]
```

References|Research i have done but with no luck.

- [The code is built of this tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/part-2-code-generation-in-dart-annotations-source-gen-and-build-runner-bbceee28697b)
- [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56388967/how-to-get-annotation-metadata-in-dart)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You already have access to the annotation properties via the `ConstantReader`

```dart
class CoreWidgetGenerator extends GeneratorForAnnotation<CoreEntity> {
  @override
  FutureOr<String> generateForAnnotatedElement(
      Element element, ConstantReader annotation, BuildStep buildStep) {
    return _generateWidgetSource(element, annotation);
  }

  String _generateWidgetSource(Element element, ConstantReader annotation) {
    print(annotation.read('label').stringValue);  
  }
}
```

However if you want to retrieve annotation information for a field of a `ClassElement` you can use a `TypeChecker`

Annotation

```dart
class CoreProperty {
  final String label;

  const CoreProperty({ this.label});
}
```

Usage

```dart
@CoreEntity(label: 'User')
class User {

  @CoreProperty(label: 'Email')
  String email;
}
```

```dart
final _coreChecker = const TypeChecker.fromRuntime(CoreProperty);

class CoreWidgetGenerator extends GeneratorForAnnotation<CoreEntity> {
  @override
  FutureOr<String> generateForAnnotatedElement(
      Element element, ConstantReader annotation, BuildStep buildStep) {
    return _generateWidgetSource(element as ClassElement, annotation);
  }

  String _generateWidgetSource(ClassElement element, ConstantReader annotation) {

    for (var f in element.fields) {
      if (_coreChecker.hasAnnotationOfExact(f)) {
        print(_coreChecker
          .firstAnnotationOfExact(f)
          .getField('label')
          .toStringValue()
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i get a enum value similar to the getField('label').toString() ? Last code part

Comment: An enum is more difficult since there is not yet a direct way to retrieve it - see the discussion at https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen/issues/178

For the ConstantReader it's possible to search the enum values for a match
`final format = MyEnum.values.singleWhere((v) => 
annotation.read('myenum').objectValue.getField(v.toString().split('.')[1]) != null);`

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Dan's answer, to get the value of an enum field:

```js
final _coreChecker = const TypeChecker.fromRuntime(CoreProperty);

class CoreWidgetGenerator extends GeneratorForAnnotation<CoreEntity> {
  @override
  FutureOr<String> generateForAnnotatedElement(
      Element element, ConstantReader annotation, BuildStep buildStep) {
    return _generateWidgetSource(element as ClassElement, annotation);
  }

  String _generateWidgetSource(ClassElement element, ConstantReader annotation) {

    for (var f in element.fields) {
      if (_coreChecker.hasAnnotationOfExact(f)) {
        final label = _coreChecker.firstAnnotationOfExact(f).getField('label');
        print(label.toStringValue());
          
        // for enum field named myEnum with an Enum type called MyEnumType
        int? myEnumIndex = _coreChecker.firstAnnotationOfExact(f)?.getField('myEnum')?.getField("index")?.toIntValue();
        MyEnumType myEnumValue = MyEnumType.values[myEnumIndex!];
        print(myEnumValue);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure the version of source_gen this answer is using by as of at least `1.4.0` you need to do `.read('label')` rather than `.getField('label')`